# how to show page on the parent of the iframe

Tags: html, iframe, parent

index.html is :

```
<iframe src="/changeDataAndBack"></iframe>
```

but the html file return back is show in the iframe ,

how to show page on the parent of the iframe

thanks

**updated:**

i changeed to this,but nothing happend :

```
<iframe src="/_openid/login?continue=/" target="_top"></iframe>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Python...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it  is ok now ,i add target="_parent" to iframe page :

```
<form class="openid" method="post" action="{{login_url}}" target="_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

Targets apply to links, not frames.

```
<a href="..." target="_top">
```

If you want to redirect, [do it server side](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback).